# How to locate value from Dynamic array in the Storage?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have the following smart contract:

```
contract StorageMapping {
  mapping(uint256 => uint256) public  f; // slot 0
  uint256[] public test; // slot 1

  constructor() {
    f[2] = 2;
    f[100] = 10;

    test.push(1);
    test.push(2);
    test.push(10);
  }
}
```

I am trying to get the first value of the array **test** from the storage with web3;

My contact address is **0x3C60f5f3930362f6B44870f6959a09eF2603DD98**

What I have tried so far:

`web3.eth.getStorageAt("0x3C60f5f3930362f6B44870f6959a09eF2603DD98", 1)`
I am getting back the correct value (length of the array):
`0x03`, which is correct. I have 3 items in the array.

Now I would like to get the first value from this array. From what I have read, you need to use keccak256 on the value stored at array length slot,
so now, first create a hash:
`web3.utils.soliditySha3("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003")`

I got back:
`0xc2575a0e9e593c00f959f8c92f12db2869c3395a3b0502d05e2516446f71f85b`

now, access the storage at retured hash:
`web3.eth.getStorageAt("0x3C60f5f3930362f6B44870f6959a09eF2603DD98","0xc2575a0e9e593c00f959f8c92f12db2869c3395a3b0502d05e2516446f71f85b")`

this will get me `0x00`, which is wrong
I expect `0x01` since that is my first item in the array.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for the advice!

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

I have figured it out.

I was putting into Keccak256 the length of the array hold at slot 1.
`web3.utils.soliditySha3("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003")`

but it should be actual slot number:

`web3.utils.soliditySha3("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001")`

This results into:

`0xb10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6`

And to get an item now:

`web3.eth.getStorageAt("<contract_address>", "0xb10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6")`

This results to:

`'0x01'`

Which is the value of the first item in the array!

So the formula to get an item in the array `T[] v` is:

`keccak256(v's slot) + n`

`n` is an index of an element in the array

and to get an array length, you need to access:

`v's slot`

More info here:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.2/internals/layout_in_storage.html#storage-hashed-encoding